# How can i set variables for each data gotten from mysql/php in flutter?

Tags: php, flutter, dart

I have a list from database and i want to create a quantity variable to increase or decrease each product's quantity that a user wants to purchase.

this is the chunk of code of how i call it

```
Container cartlist(imagelink, productName, price) {
return Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 17, left: 17, top: 5),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.white,
    boxShadow: [
      BoxShadow(
        color: Colors.grey,
        offset: Offset(0, 1),
        blurRadius: 5,
      ),
    ],
  ),
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: [
      Container(
        child: Image.network(
          imagelink,
          fit: BoxFit.contain,
          width: 120,
          height: 100,
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              child: Text(
                productName,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
              child: Text("Quantity"),
            ),
            Container(
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  FaIcon(
                    FontAwesomeIcons.dollarSign,
                    size: 14,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: Text(
                      price,
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  quantity++;
                  print(quantity);
                });
              },
              child: Icon(Icons.add),
            ),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
              child: Text('"' + quantity.toString() + '"'),
            ),
            InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  if (quantity == 1) {
                  } else {
                    quantity--;
                    print(quantity);
                  }
                });
              },
              child: Icon(Icons.remove),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

}

then i call it with

```
                  for (Map document in snapshot.data)
                    cartlist(
                      document['productimage'],
                      document['productname'],
                      document['productprice'],
                    ),
```

from streambuilder...

How can i get to increase the quantity individually for each product so that all quantity "1" wont' be increased at the same time.
anytime i click on increase or decrease, it goes for both.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How about you implement a new method that will be used to either increase or decrease quantity. The in the method pass the item id so that only that individual item quantity gets updated.

On tapping the + the quantity get increased and on - the quantity get decreased.

Comment: I don't really get this?

Comment: and how to implement this... Thanks